# Hibernate : reuse the same foreign key if x.equals(y)

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's take for example these two entities :

*City :*

```
<class name="City" table="city">
    <id name="id" column="id"/>
    <property name="city_name" column="city_name"/>
    <property name="country_name" column="country_name"/>
</class>
```

*Person :*

```
<class name="Person" table="person">
    <id name="id" column="id"/>
    <property name="name" column="name"/>    
    <many-to-one cascade="save-update" name="city" column="city_id" class="City"/>
</class>
```

`City.equals()` implementation returns `true` if both `city_name` and `coutry_name` are the same.

If I save two `Person` during one session :

```
Person person1 = new Person("Peter");
Person person2 = new Person("John");

City city1 = new City("Paris", "France");
City city2 = new City("Paris", "France");

person1.setCity(city1);    
person2.setCity(city2);

session.save(person1);
session.save(person2);
```

Hibernate will produce the following records :

*city :*

```
| id |  name  | city_id |
-------------------------
| 1  |  Peter |    1    |
| 2  |  John  |    2    |
```

*person :*

```
| id |  city_name | country_name |
----------------------------------
| 1  |    Paris   |    France    |
| 2  |    Paris   |    France    |
```

But can I tell Hibernate to reuse the same `city_id` in `person` when `cityX.equals(cityY)` ?

**EDIT :**

I should have clarified that `city1` cannot be the same instance as `city2`. For the purpose of brevity, I can't describe the full problem I am facing. In the actual case the table can contain duplicates elements, I am just trying to save some space by grouping some specific elements. Thank you!

Comment: Think you're probably running into an issue in this case because you're using a new City object per person. For Hibernate to recognize that they are in fact the same object, the same object(ie city1) needs to be re-used. Normally you could look up the City in the DB by name & country and use that object as many times as needed by assigning it to each person.

Comment: This may not be the answer to your question, but a pointer with regards to database design: you really should have a UNIQUE constraint on your city_name and country_name fields.  This would catch errors that duplicate data rather than leaving them to perhaps cause obscure failures at a later point.

Comment: Why the city instance restriction? Using different instances for the same object in the database or to save multiple records and depure them makes no sense, at least to me.

Comment: @Gamb Actually I could use the same instances but I would have to do some filtering on my data collection. It can be done using a hash set but I didn't want to "reinvent the wheel" if such a feature exists in Hibernate. I apologize for the obscurity of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single `City` object and assign the same object to both entities. You'll want to persist this `City` object first so the association is made with an existing object.

*There's a catch here.*

Since you're assigning the same value to both `Person` instances, the cascade shouldn't be actually done but the `City` should be deleted if it's going to be an orphan after dropping a `Person`.

In your particular case, since you're dealing with cities an existing table with many cities could be a good option to allow you to assign a pre-existing city to a new person, in case you want to create a third `Person` in `Paris` after deleting *Peter* and *John*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Person person1 = new Person("Peter");
Person person2 = new Person("John");

City city1 = new City("Paris", "France");

person1.setCity(city1);    
session.save(person1);
person2.setCity(city1);
session.save(person2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have something different in mind, but here's how I would handle this:

1. First of all, I would put a unique index on the following fields of the city table (city_name, country_name)
2. Of course I would let Hibernate know about this unique index
3. Instead of `City city1 = new City("Paris", "France")` I would

   ```
   //use session.createQuery or createCriteria here  
   City city = findByNameAndCountry("Paris", "France")   
   if (city == null){  
       city = new City("Paris", "France");  
       session.save(city)  
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have city_name and country_name as primary key. So in this situation you can not insert same value to the database.
like..

```
City city1 = new City("Paris", "France");
City city2 = new City("Paris", "France");
```

So you must have one city object with same values. Then it wont duplicate.

Don't forget to override hashCode() according to the equals() method.

Comment: The person table would then contain both city name and country which makes the city table useless.

Answer (score 0):

City is an entity and its equality is dependant on its identity. As long as you associate two different citys with a two person you will get two person.

To avoid this you have to only create a city object if it doesn't exist and otherwise use the already existing one.

Also a problem: What happens if two cities in the same country happen to have the same name? They wouldn't be the same city but would share the same identity.